# How to change the micrometer's version of Spring-boot-actuator 2.3.0

Tags: spring-boot, influxdb, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

In our project, we use spring-boot 2.3.0.RELEASE.

Default, spring-boot-actuator is the 2.3.0 and it uses the 1.5.1 micrometer-core.
However, I want it use the 1.9.0 micrometer because I want to use the 1.9.0 micrometer-registry-influx.
I loaded the 1.9.0 micrometer-core in maven ,but it makes no sense.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Our spring-boot version is not to be allowed to change, so I want to change the micrometer's version in 2.3.0.RELEASE spring-boot-actuator.What should I do next?

Comment: THat version isn't compatible with Spring Boot 2.3 so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade Boot so that it will bring in the latest Micrometer.
You can force your build system to resolve 1.9.x but you might need to do it for multiple dependencies (e.g.: micrometer-core, xyz-registry, etc.)